# Python - Reading specific column from SQL output stored in a variable

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I have a basic question here. I am pulling a SQL output as below:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("""select store_name,count(*) from stores group by store_name""")
data = cur.fetchall()
```

The output of the above SQL is as below:

```
Store_1,23
Store_2,13
Store_3,43
Store_4,2
```

I am trying to read column 1 (store_name) in the above output.

Expected Output:

```
Store_1
Store_2
Store_3
Store_4
```

Could anyone advice on how could I have this done. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, I guess just correcting your SQL will give you the desired result. Fetch `distinct` store_name

```
select distinct store_name from stores
```

---

**Edit**

Response to comment:

Try following:

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = cur.fetchall() 
list(map(itemgetter(0), data)) # your answer
```

Comment: I have fetched an output that is currently stored in the variable called 'data'. This currently has two columns. I am trying to filter out the first column (store_name) and return that back from data.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you can simply append the following lines:

```
for rows in data:
    print(rows[0])
```

hope this helps.

BTW: I am not on the computer and have not crosschecked the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Harvard's CS50 web [class](https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2018/notes/3/) has the following which I think helps you in it's last 3 lines.

```
  import os    
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine
  from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

  engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")) # database engine object from SQLAlchemy that manages connections to the database
                                                    # DATABASE_URL is an environment variable that indicates where the database lives
  db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))    # create a 'scoped session' that ensures different users' interactions with the
                                                    # database are kept separate

  flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall() # execute this SQL command and return all of the results
  for flight in flights
      print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.") # for every flight, print out the flight info
```

So in your case I suppose its:

```
results = db.execute( <PUT YOUR SQL QUERY HERE> )
for row in results:
    print(row.store_name)
```